# Ion row show all elements in same line

Tags: html, css, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have to show inverted currency rate in case inverse icon (rotated swap icon) is clicked. However my inverted icon always slides into newline. How I can I avoid that? I need to keep that in same line as with other elements in the row. I have nothing on the left side.

```
  <ion-row>

   <div col-7 offset-5 no-padding text-right>
     <ion-label  *ngIf="!showInverted" no-margin  class="rate label-tx">1 {{transaction.SendCurrency}} = {{transaction.ExchangeRate | amountFormat}} {{transaction.PayoutCurrency }}</ion-label>
     <ion-label *ngIf="showInverted" no-margin  class="rate label-tx">1 {{transaction.PayoutCurrency}} = {{1/transaction.ExchangeRate | amountFormat}} {{transaction.SendCurrency }}</ion-label>
     <button (click)="showInvertedRate()" ion-button clear color="dark">  <ion-icon name="swap" class="rotate90"></ion-icon></button>
   </div>
 </ion-row>

In my Ts file:

     showInvertedRate()
      {
        this.showInverted = !this.showInverted ;
      }
```

My Scss:

```
.rotate90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Does your inverted currency value change in width, when invert is clicked?

Comment: yes it does depending on currency. How could this be handled a small snippet will be great or you can work on my provided snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since u said that, the content resizes, the button doesnt get enough space, hence it goes to next line.

The solution to this will be assign fixed with to button, group remaining content and use

```
width:calc(100% - 30px);
```

for the remaing content.

Note that `width:calc(100% - 30px)` should also take into account any margin, applied to button or the content.

```css
.inner{
  display:inline:block;
  width:calc(100% - 30px); /*30px. should be same as button width */ 
}
.buuton{
  width:30px;
}
```

```html
<ion-row>

  <div col-7 offset-5 no-padding text-right>
    <div class="inner">
      <ion-label *ngIf="!showInverted" no-margin class="rate label-tx">1 </ion-label>
      <ion-label *ngIf="showInverted" no-margin class="rate label-tx">1 </ion-label>
    </div>
    <button (click)="showInvertedRate()" ion-button clear color="dark">  <ion-icon name="swap" class="rotate90"></ion-icon></button>
  </div>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Trying this on my solution.